missing ntbtlog.txt after enabling boot logging (with "inaccessible boot device" error)
Missing C:\Windows\ntbtlog.txt after enabling boot logging: normal with "inaccessible boot device" startup error?
To put it in other words: if Windows Server 2019 can't boot, and fails with "inaccessible boot device" - I shouldn't expect boot logging to work, correct?



A bit of context:

Windows Server 2019 VM on ESXi 7.03
refused to be patched in the last two monthly Windows Update cycles - "Windows couldn't apply updates, rolling back" - or something like that
my last attempt to patch with two 2024-08 Windows Update patches - resulted in "INACCESSIBLE BOOT DEVICE" stop error after a reboot. This is unusual as we have other VMs that refuse to be patched in a similar way - yet this VM is the first one with this issue
the vmdk is fine (no errors), the file system is fine (disk checks, sfc /scannow all come back clear
I followed all the steps I could follow in "Advanced troubleshooting for Stop error 7B or Inaccessible_Boot_Device" MS KB article - still the same issue. (Some of the steps - I couldn't follow as, say bootrec /rebuildbcd would result in "access denied" and some of the instructions appear to be invalid or missing necessary information.)
at this point, I am less worried about getting this particular VM to boot (it's not critical), and more - about what to do in similar situations going forward:

if the file system is good, the registry is good - then what does it take to repair the boot components so the server could boot again as it was before the failed update? (Yes, I know, "restore from snapshot / restore point / most recent backup" - yah, with you here - asking a different question here, thank you.)
how to find out exactly what and where something is failing during the boot process?



Thanks!
